# In pandas / python, ternary operator to replace NaN in string column with value from different column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We are trying to replace NaN values that are appearing in a string column in our pandas dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': [np.nan, 'Team3'], 'col2': ['Team1', 'Team2']}
dd = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dd
```

[image]

None of these 3 attempted solutions are working.

```
# dd['col3'] = np.where(type(dd['col1']) == float, dd['col2'], dd['col1'])
# dd = dd.assign(col3 = lambda x: x.col2 if type(x.col1) == float else x.col1)
# dd = dd.assign(col3 = lambda x: x.col2 if np.isnan(x.col1) else x.col1)
```

[image]

Our goal is to have col3 have the values `Team1` and `Team3`. Even better to simply re-assign `col1` to these values. I understand why the 3rd attempt is not working, as we cannot call np.isnan() on string values. Not sure why the other 2 approaches are not working (I checked and NaN is float type), or what we could do here.

Comment: Try to utilise df['col1'].isnull()

Comment: What about `df.loc[df['col1'].isna(), 'col1'] = df['col2']`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
d = {'col1': [np.nan, 'Team3'], 'col2': ['Team1', 'Team2']}
dd = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def check_missing_values(value):
    if value is np.nan:
        return True
    return False

dd['col3'] = dd.apply(lambda row: row['col2'] if check_missing_values(row['col1']) else row['col1'], axis=1)
```